# Prove, using only the definition of O(), that 2^sqrt(x) is not O(x^10)

Tags: big-o

Prove, using only the definition of O(), that 2^sqrt(x) is not O(x^10).

I have been doing a few exercises on Big O and this is the first time I have encountered the variable in the exponent. I was wondering how to disprove this function. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What *is* the definition of Big O? Pick a suitable value of n; the relation between f and g does not change. (Also I suspect it should be written as `O(2^sqrt(x))` in the question..)

Answer (score 1):

you can use limits to prove it. 
`lim (2^sqrt(x))/x^10)` when x->infinity then this limit is Infinity, which means that  `2^sqrt(x) is not O(x^10)`.